# Player follows finger drag, but slowly

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using orthographic camera and moving the player on touch. 
transform.x is the left left/right movement and
transform.z is the left top/down movement

My code is working fine but it is quite slow, as it does not accurately follow the dragging finger.

Here is my code:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
        foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches) {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, 100)) {
                if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
                    var cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform.InverseTransformPoint (0, 0, 0);
                    player.transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (touch.position.x , touch.position.y, cameraTransform.z - 0.5f));
                }

                // when touch finish, stop the player where it is last time.
                if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended){
                    player.rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

I need a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try adding the increment to position instead of assigning it: `player.transform.position += Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (touch.position.x , touch.position.y, cameraTransform.z - 0.5f));`

Comment: What do you mean by 'slow'? Is it lagging? Where are you calling this code?

Comment: Aren't you missing the case for handling TouchPhase.Stationary? You should also use touch.position for the Raycast. Also if you're not using the information stored in hit there's little reason to do a Raycast at all.